# How to pass current month and year in input parameters in pl sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to pass the month and year in a plsql as input parameters. I want the month and year to be the default values as of current month and current year if i'm passing null values.

Comment: You can use `to_char` function. e.g. `to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')` - it will be year. But it will be char value

Comment: Why are you passing the month and year as separate parameters and not a date? You could just pass the 1st of the month (eg. `trunc(sysdate, 'mm')`) rather than needing two separate parameters. This has the advantage of already having the validation in place to make sure you don't pass a month of 13, etc

Comment: I agree with @Boneist. A DATE should be passed as a date and not in parts. You could EXTRACT the requirement elements as and when required.

Answer (score 1):

A **DATE** should be passed as a date and not in parts. You could **EXTRACT** the requirement elements as and when required.

Pass the **SYSDATE** as **DEFAULT IN** parameter:

```
p_date DATE default SYSDATE
```

And then **EXTRACT** the elements:

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE ,
  2    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)  AS curr_year ,
  3    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) AS curr_month ,
  4    EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE)   AS curr_day
  5  FROM dual;

SYSDATE    CURR_YEAR CURR_MONTH   CURR_DAY
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------
03-NOV-15       2015         11          3
```

Depending on your requirement, you could use **TO_CHAR**, however, the data type of the result will be **string**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE ,
  2    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')  AS curr_year ,
  3    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') AS curr_month ,
  4    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD')   AS curr_day
  5  FROM dual;

SYSDATE   CURR_YEAR CURR_MONTH CURR_DAY
--------- --------- ---------- --------
03-NOV-15 2015      11         03
```

Answer (score 0):

First variant -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_poc(
   year_num  IN NUMBER DEFAULT to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')),
   month_num IN NUMBER DEFAULT to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'mm'))) IS
BEGIN
   ....
END;
```

Second (is better, with a date in input parameter) -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_poc(date_in IN DATE) IS
   year_num    NUMBER;
   month_num   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   year_num    := to_number(to_char(nvl(date_in, sysdate), 'yyyy'));
   month_num   := to_number(to_char(nvl(date_in, sysdate), 'mm'));
   ...
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a default for your parameters as suggested in the other answers. But those default values will only take effect when you dont pass anything as parameter. Giving null as parameter value will not trigger the default value. For example

```
create or replace 
function TEST_FN( p_month in number default extract( MONTH from sysdate ) )
return varchar2
as
begin
    return 'month='||nvl( p_month, -1);
end;
```

A `select TEST_FN() from dual;` will result in `month=11` for november, and selecting `select TEST_FN(null) from dual;` gives `month=-1`.

If you want to replace a `null` with some default value use `nvl(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure p1(my_year int default null, my_month integer default null)
as
  lyear  int := nvl(my_year, to_char(sysdate,'yyyy'));
  lmonth int := nvl(my_month, to_char(sysdate,'mm'));
begin 

  dbms_output.put_line(lyear);
  dbms_output.put_line(lmonth);
end;
```

test

```
begin 
p1;
p1(2010);
p1(null,12);
p1(2009,10);
end;
```

output

```
2015
11
2010
11
2015
12
2009
10
```